# Jenkins agents slow

Tags: performance, jenkins, agents

My Jenkins builds are 5 to 20 times slower on my build agents while using Jenkins and as compared to 
- running the build in command line on the build agents
- running the build on my workstation

What can be causing the issue? I have attempted to add memory to the environments and also set env variable JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS to -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m

no change at all. Are Jenkins agents very slow or am I missing sth?

note that both environments tested against have more CPU and memory than needed (8 to 24G) etc. again running the build in command line works as fast as expected.

Comment: I have the same issue with my test suite. It's slow (25 min) when run through the agent, but fast (1.5 min) when started through the console on the same machine.